# Spent 5 hours trying to fix react-native init

Tags: react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

`1. Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`2. An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.`

[image]

[image]

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 but it is still saying I dont have it

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Comment: Have you try this? 1) brew cleanup -d -v    
2) brew install cocoapods
3) gem install ffi -- --enable-system-libffi
4) sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: @Miteshjadav I ran your 3rd command and got: Error installing ffi:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Answer (score 0):

Try to install 2 steps older version of react native

1. Node JS is required for react-native
   1.1. Download 2 steps order vesion of https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
2. Init your react-native with 2 steps older version
   2.2 `npx react-native init MyAwesomeApp --version="react-native@0.68.0"`
   https://reactnative.dev/versions

This is best practice for your any app development in react-native as per my thought.

Do not need to downgrade your software version like Gem, Ruby or etc. Just intial any react-native app with older version which helps you for start developing as quick as possible.

Comment: Ran your command, got this: Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@react-native@0.68.0
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "react-native@0.68.0" of package "react-native@react-native@0.68.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Comment: your are doing wrong command, please do get proper understanding.